# How prove $\sum_{k=0}^n {2n-k\choose n-k} 2^k=4^n$

Tags: calculus

show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {2n-k\choose n-k} 2^k=4^n$$

Have you other good methods, such as calculus methods?

this problem is from [How prove this $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\binom{2n-k}{n}}{2^{2n-k}}=1 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508944/how-prove-this-sum-k-0n-frac-binom2n-kn22n-k-1)

Comment: Look at (5.20) in "Concrete Mathematics" by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik.

Comment: 5.20 meaning page 520? Thank you

Comment: Equation (5.20). In my edition of the book, it is on page 167.

Comment: Thank you,But I think is very ugly,I think have nice methods

Comment: I would like to see your nice methods.

Comment: Why is this tagged `calculcus`? Are you refusing combinatorial or algebraic proofs? There are nice answers at your link.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your previous question [How prove this $\sum\_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\binom{2n-k}{n}}{2^{2n-k}}=1 $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508944/how-prove-this-sum-k-0n-frac-binom2n-kn22n-k-1) ? The transformations to bring that question to this one are essentially trivial, amounting only to multiplying out terms and one use of binomial reflection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left({n+k\atop k}\right)2^{-k}=2^{n}$.
This because $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left({2n-k\atop n-k}\right)2^{k}=2^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left({n+k\atop k}\right)2^{-k}$. (switch order of addition)

Go out from $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left({n+k\atop k}\right)2^{-k}=2^{n}$
and set $s:=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\left({n+1+k\atop k}\right)2^{-k}$

Then $s=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left({n+k\atop k-1}\right)2^{-k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left({n+k\atop k}\right)2^{-k}=1+2^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left({n+1+k\atop k}\right)2^{-k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left({n+k\atop k}\right)2^{-k}=1+2^{-1}\left(s-\left({2n+2\atop n+1}\right)2^{-n-1}\right)+2^{n}-1+\left({2n+1\atop n+1}\right)2^{-n-1}=2^{n}+2^{-1}s$ 
leading to $s=2^{n+1}$

Note that $\left({2n+2\atop n+1}\right)=2\left({2n+1\atop n+1}\right)$